# Fop 2.2 with Barcode4J and zxing for QR codes

Tags: java, zxing, apache-fop, barcode4j

I create a project in Eclipse using FOP 2.2. Barcodes and QR codes are required in the PDF files created by the project. Barcode4j is able to create barcodes, however, qr codes are created only if there is a zxing core, which, based on this, [Apache FOP 1.1 QRCodes with zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292995/apache-fop-1-1-qrcodes-with-zxing) needs to be downloaded from CVS Repository. I did everything that is said in this post, but when I try to create a qr code

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <barcode:barcode xmlns:barcode="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns" message="test">
      <barcode:qr/>
    </barcode:barcode>
  </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>
```

I get an error.

```
org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeException: No barcode configuration element not found
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeUtil.createBarcodeGenerator(BarcodeUtil.java:110)
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeUtil.createBarcodeGenerator(BarcodeUtil.java:146)
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.fop.BarcodeElement.getDimension(BarcodeElement.java:76)
at org.apache.fop.fo.flow.InstreamForeignObject.prepareIntrinsicSize(InstreamForeignObject.java:112)
at org.apache.fop.fo.flow.InstreamForeignObject.getIntrinsicWidth(InstreamForeignObject.java:125)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.AbstractGraphicsLayoutManager.getInlineArea(AbstractGraphicsLayoutManager.java:60)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.AbstractGraphicsLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(AbstractGraphicsLayoutManager.java:116)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.LineLayoutManager.collectInlineKnuthElements(LineLayoutManager.java:698)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.LineLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(LineLayoutManager.java:627)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockLayoutManager.getNextChildElements(BlockLayoutManager.java:141)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockStackingLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(BlockStackingLayoutManager.java:289)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(BlockLayoutManager.java:113)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(BlockLayoutManager.java:105)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableCellLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(TableCellLayoutManager.java:191)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.RowGroupLayoutManager.createElementsForRowGroup(RowGroupLayoutManager.java:120)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.RowGroupLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(RowGroupLayoutManager.java:63)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager.getKnuthElementsForRowIterator(TableContentLayoutManager.java:270)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(TableContentLayoutManager.java:212)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(TableLayoutManager.java:272)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.FlowLayoutManager.getNextChildElements(FlowLayoutManager.java:223)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.FlowLayoutManager.addChildElements(FlowLayoutManager.java:147)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.FlowLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(FlowLayoutManager.java:116)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.FlowLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(FlowLayoutManager.java:69)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.getNextKnuthElements(PageBreaker.java:251)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.getNextBlockList(AbstractBreaker.java:770)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.getNextBlockList(PageBreaker.java:178)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.getNextBlockList(PageBreaker.java:158)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.AbstractBreaker.doLayout(AbstractBreaker.java:389)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker.doLayout(PageBreaker.java:112)
at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageSequenceLayoutManager.activateLayout(PageSequenceLayoutManager.java:141)
at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.endPageSequence(AreaTreeHandler.java:267)
at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence.endOfNode(PageSequence.java:130)
at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:360)
at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.endElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:190)
at org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.endElement(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:263)
at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1401)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2402)
at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1376)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2402)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.applyTemplateToNode(TransformerImpl.java:2272)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transformNode(TransformerImpl.java:1358)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:711)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1275)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1253)
at embedding.ExampleXML2PDF.main(ExampleXML2PDF.java:99)
```

I would like to understand the reason for this error, and also to find out whether there are alternative ways to generate barcodes and qr codes using FOP.

Comment: The CVS repository must be used not only to find the appropriate zxing-core jar, but also to **build from source the Barcode4J plugin**.

Comment: @lfurini Thanks for the answer, though I already did it.

Comment: Strange, I was able to reproduce the error using the released Barcode4J jar, and everything went ok after using the jar compiled from the cvs source. As you have the plugin source at hand, can you check whether the class `org.krysalis.barcode4j.tools.ZXingUtil` is present?